# How to set a variable between 1 and 0, and how to check the FOC is greater or small than 0 by assumption?

Tags: assumptions

I have the following notebook:

```
$Assumptions = Flatten[{Thread[{c0, c1, p, w, e} > 0],Thread[0 <= {{r, i, x, alpha, beta, gamma, {1 - alpha - beta - gamma}, {1 + r - i}, {1 - x}} <= 1}], Element[{c0, c1, p, w, e, r, i, x, alpha, beta, gamma, {1 - alpha - beta - gamma}, {1 + r - i}, {1 - x}}, Reals]}]

case11 = ((1 - x)*alpha*(c0 + e + w + w/(1 + r - i)));

case12 = ((1 - x)*gamma*(c0 + w - p/(1 + r - i)));

case13 = x*(c0 - p);

case21 = ((1 - x)*(1 - alpha - beta - gamma)*(c0 + c1/(1 + r - i) + e+ w+ w/(1 + r - i)));

case22 = ((1 - x)*beta*(c0 + c1/(1 + r - i) - p/(1 + r - i) + w));

case23 = (x*(c0 - p));

f = case11 + case12 + case13;

h = case21 + case22 + case23;

g = e + w + w/(1 + r - i);

occc=g/h;

ocdc=g/f;
```

I would like to check if `D[occc,p]` is positive, i tried to run the `Positive`, but seems it does not work, it did not give me True of False as a result. I believe I need to have more condition to make `D[occc,p` to be positive, I would like to know those conditions,the word "conditions" i would like to see is something like c0>p, can *Mathematica* tell me?
Thanks

Comment: It is impossible to help until you clarify your assumptions. As written, they make no sense.

Comment: Hi, my assumption is c0, c1, w, e, p all greater than 0 and they are all real number. but r, i, x, alpha, beta, gamma are all between 0 and 1. Particularly, x, alpha, beta, gamma are probabilities; r, i are nominal interest rate and inflation respectively.  Sorry, I am completely newbie to mathematica, and do not know what it the meaning of each syntax, the assumption syntax is from some question's answer. Sorry if I made any misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5):

It can be zero but not negative. To show this we first rewrite the assumptions so they are actually usable, removing those that are redundant and getting the `Thread` to work by getting rid of inner lists (things in curly braces).

```
$Assumptions = 
  Flatten[{Thread[{c0, c1, p, w, e} > 0], 
    Thread[0 <= {r, i, x, alpha, beta, gamma, 
       1 - alpha - beta - gamma, 1 + r - i, 1 - x} <= 1], 
    Element[{c0, c1, p, w, e, r, i, x, alpha, beta, gamma}, Reals]}];

case11 = ((1 - x) alpha (c0 + e + w + w/(1 + r - i)));
case12 = ((1 - x) gamma (c0 + w - p/(1 + r - i)));
case13 = x*(c0 - p);
case21 = ((1 - x) (1 - alpha - beta - gamma) (c0 + c1/(1 + r - i) + 
      e + w + w/(1 + r - i)));
case22 = ((1 - x) beta (c0 + c1/(1 + r - i) - p/(1 + r - i) + w));
case23 = (x*(c0 - p));

f = case11 + case12 + case13;
h = case21 + case22 + case23;
g = e + w + w/(1 + r - i);

occc = g/h;
ocdc = g/f;
```

Now compute the derivative and break it into numerator and denominator.

```
deriv = Together[D[occc, p]];
{numer, denom} = Through[{Numerator, Denominator}[deriv]]

(* Out[194]= {(-e + e i - e r - 2 w + i w - r w) (-beta - x + beta x + 
    i x - r x), (-c0 + alpha c0 - c1 + alpha c1 - e + alpha e + 
   beta e + c0 gamma + c1 gamma + e gamma + c0 i - alpha c0 i + e i - 
   alpha e i - beta e i - c0 gamma i - e gamma i + beta p - c0 r + 
   alpha c0 r - e r + alpha e r + beta e r + c0 gamma r + e gamma r - 
   2 w + 2 alpha w + beta w + 2 gamma w + i w - alpha i w - 
   gamma i w - r w + alpha r w + gamma r w - alpha c0 x + c1 x - 
   alpha c1 x + e x - alpha e x - beta e x - c0 gamma x - c1 gamma x -
    e gamma x + alpha c0 i x - e i x + alpha e i x + beta e i x + 
   c0 gamma i x + e gamma i x + p x - beta p x - i p x - 
   alpha c0 r x + e r x - alpha e r x - beta e r x - c0 gamma r x - 
   e gamma r x + p r x + 2 w x - 2 alpha w x - beta w x - 
   2 gamma w x - i w x + alpha i w x + gamma i w x + r w x - 
   alpha r w x - gamma r w x)^2} *)
```

The denominator is a square, hence nonnegative. So all that needs to be tested for negativity is the numerator. We can use `FindInstance` to tell us if that can happen, as below.

```
FindInstance[Flatten[{numer < 0, $Assumptions}], 
 Variables[D[occc, p]]]

(* Out[197]= {} *)
```

Or use `Refine`-- it automatically absorbs the `$Assumptions`.

```
Refine[numer < 0]

(* Out[198]= False *)
```

So the expression is in fact nonnegative. It can be zero, as a simple `FindInstance` computation will indicate.

Comment: Hi, if I tried Daniel's way to check the if FOC of occc wrt to e is positive, and `FindInstance` gives me the following `{{alpha -> 0, beta -> 0, gamma -> 0, e -> 1, w -> 1, i -> 0, r -> 0, 
  x -> 1, c0 -> 1/2, c1 -> 1, p -> 1}}` 
how to interpret this result? Is it the condition that for `D[occc,e]` is <0?

Comment: That is a solution for whatever you queried in `FindInstance`. If the query was `FindInstance[D[occc,e]<0,...]` then that gives values for `alpha, beta,...` for which the inequality holds. That is to say, it is a sufficient but not necessary condition.

Comment: so that means there is a case for `D[occc,p]` is less than 0.
how should I do for make this case as a symbolic equation? that is, expressing if this case fulfilled `D[occc,p]`<0 by an equation